# Child div not resizing properly on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using three div tags like this

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <div id='sub'>
            Child div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#main
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
#content{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:5px solid blue;
}
#sub
{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

so i kept everything auto. But even when i resize or change the margin of main parent the last child not adapting to it.

I am not sure what may be the problem. But when i set width and height as 100% in resize or margin change event it seems adapting.

Can anyone help me out in this? And also is there anyway to detect the parent div attribute changes in some event??

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/466hv8u4/1/)

Comment: what is the issue with this? http://jsfiddle.net/466hv8u4/2/

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sub').css({
    width: $('#content').width(),
    height: $('#content').height()
  });


  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#main').css('margin-left', '0px');
    $('#sub').css({
      width: $('#content').width(),
      height: $('#content').height()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
#content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
#sub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div id='sub'>
      Child div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>margin0</button>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/466hv8u4/4/)

Comment: Is there no way to sort this out without getting in jquery??

Comment: you have set height and width of #sub on Load event then you need to reset on click event too.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the width from JS. Try this.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <div id='sub'>
            Child div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button>margin0</button>

#main
{
    margin-left:-100px;
}
#content{
    border:5px solid blue;
}
#sub{
    display: block;
    border:1px solid red;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sub').css('height',$('#content').height());


$('button').click(function(){
    $('#main').css('margin-left','0px');
});

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/466hv8u4/10/)